# I'm trying to create a new file within a folder in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following along with the 'Rails Crash Course' book and it is telling me to create a file within a folder in a rails application that already exists.

I've searched the whole book but I can't find the instructions to create a file. I feel like this should be easy but I have searched online and cannot find a straight answer.

Here's an example:
**Create a new file named app/views/posts/index.html.erb and add the following code...**

Here's another:
**Create the file app/views/text_posts/_text_post.html.erb and open for editing...**

Anyone got the solution?

Comment: What is your development environment?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably overthinking it. Open up your favorite text editor (I suggest [Atom](https://atom.io/)), type text into the blank document, click save, browse to the folder where you installed Rails, and then drill down to the subfolder that the instructions indicate.

For your first example, after clicking save, go through these directories:

1. where you installed Rails
2. app
3. views
4. posts

And give your new file a name: `index.html.erb` and click save.

Done!

Comment: i already tried that but when i load the localhost page the code i input to the file doesnt show up on the webpage. do i have to generate something from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal command line:

```
$> cd *appname*  
$> touch app/views/posts/index.html.erb
```

Also, `$> rails generate scaffold *model*` will create these views for you.

All the best

Comment: okay it created the file but im not sure what model to generate. would it be posts???

Comment: Yep. `rails generate model posts`